# Perfectly align listings when using media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I got my first set of listings styling and centered the way I want it to be. Now I want to apply the same thing in my second listings except with a little bit more info in it.

Now it seems to be a little bit off when you go into F12 mode to change display to iPhone and the width looks a bit off in the second listings. I want the width to be exactly the same as the first listings.

Just to note, I like the width in desktop mode, **I just want the width to be exactly the same as in the first set of listings for my second set of listings.**

*Run the code snippet to see what I'm talking about. It will make a lot more sense when you see it.*

```css
.listContainer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

div.listContainer ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

div.listContainer li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px 50px;
  margin: 7px;
}

div.accomodationLists ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

div.accomodationLists li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px 50px;
  margin: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 440px) {
  .listContainer {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  div.listContainer li {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 7px auto;
  }
  .accomodationLists {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  div.accomodationLists li {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 7px auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- First listing -->

<div class="listContainer">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Second listing -->

<div class="accomodationLists">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Mini title
      <br>
      <br> Small description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
      <br>
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    </li>

    <li>
      Mini title number 2
      <br>
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: if your width is 600px on desktop then you 600px width on mob also ??

Comment: As you have used `display:inline-block` it will take the width of the text inside  try to increase the text you will face the same issue in the first listing as well. So basically you have to set a width in your media query and use reset css so that browser doesn't take default css

Comment: @Vitorino fernandes So I removed (display:inline-block) and then changed my (div.accomodationLists li) to (div.accomodationLists ul) and played around with my paddings. That seemed to kind of do the trick and it worked out just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you have used `display:inline-block` it will take the `width` of the text inside it as you have added the same content for all the element in first listing it were not facing any issue once you change the content of any one of the element you will face the same issue as the second listing

You can use reset css to remove all the properties which are added by browsers

```
*{
    margin:0; /* removes default margin give by browsers */
    padding:0; /* removes default padding give by browsers */
    box-sizing:border-box; /* this gives padding and border from inside */
}
```